# Solving a differential equation numerically to plot particle path

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I'm trying to plot the evolution of a particle in an accretion disk by solving the equation

$$2X\frac{\partial X}{\partial\tau}=V_R(X,\tau)$$

where I have found $V_R$ numerically to be

$$V_R(X_i,\tau_n)=-\frac{3}{2X_i^2\sigma_{i,n}}\bigg[\frac{X_{i+1}\sigma_{i+1,n}-X_{i-1}\sigma_{i-1,n}}{2\Delta X}\bigg]$$

and I have all values of the surface density $\sigma_{i,j}$.

So I assume I need to integrate $V_R$ with respect to time $\tau$ in order to get $X=f(\tau)$

I'm confused when it comes to trying to do this numerically. The first initial condition is $X(0)=\sqrt{0.9}$.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated because I've been stuck on this problem for way too long.

Comment: Is $X$ a single variable (as seems to be implied by the first equation) or a vector (as implied by the second)?  If it's a vector, what does $2 X \frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau}$ mean?

Comment: $X$ starts off as a single variable but to solve numerically I consider $X$ to be discrete with values $X_i$, $i=1,2,...,100$ and $X_1=\Delta X=0.02$. Time $\tau$ is written in a similar way, but with much smaller timesteps.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this numerically you would start by rearranging to get

$$\frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau} = \frac{V_R(X,\tau)}{2X} $$

and then starting with $X(0)$, you find $X(\Delta\tau)$ using:

$$ X(\Delta\tau) = X(0) + \frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau}\Delta\tau $$

and so on

$$ X((n+1)\Delta\tau) = X(n\Delta\tau) + \frac{\partial X}{\partial \tau}\Delta\tau $$

It is important that your $X$ variable be continuous. In other words, don't store it as $i$ or $X_i$, but rather as $X$ (otherwise you may find your particle doesn't move anywhere!). And then when you evaluate $\partial X/\partial\tau$ you can either round $X$ to the nearest $X_i$ or you can interpolate.

Comment: Thanks again @lemon. I got it to work with the following code:
 $$X(i+1) = X(i) + (dt / (2 X(i) ) ) V( round(X(i)/dx),i)$$
  
Now I've calculated that that when $X_0 = \sqrt{1.1}$, it takes a time of 0.2117 to reach the outer boundary at $X = 2$. I need to write 0.2117 as a function of $X_0$. It seems I have to work the iteration backwards in order to end up with a function of the original $X_0$, but I keep running into problems. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: You currently have $X(t)$. Plot $0.2117-t$ (as the $y$-axis) against $X(t)$.

Comment: @AlexM < I forgot to add this to alert you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want to integrate $V_R$ with respect to $\tau$.  You want to solve the differential equation $2 X \frac{dX}{d\tau} = V_R(X,\tau)$ with initial condition $X(0) = \sqrt{0.9}$.

Unless you have very special requirements, you shouldn't try to re-invent the wheel.  There is lots of good software for numerical solution of differential equations, and you can access it easily through Maple, Matlab, Mathematica etc.

Comment: But is it possible to use a simple Matlab function to solve this when my solutions need to be a vector in order to plot the path the particle traces?

Would the following work: $X^{2}(\tau)=\intop_{0}^{\tau}V_{R}(X,s)ds$, finding this integral for each discrete value of $\tau$?

Comment: No, because $V_R$ depends on the unknown $X$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "my solutions need to be a vector in order to plot the path the particle traces".  Plotting should be a separate issue from finding $X(t)$.